# Diferencias entre dudar que / dudar de que

Tags: gramática, selección-de-palabras, sintaxis

1. Dudo que estemos en las nubes.
2. Dudo de que estemos en las nubes.
3. Ella dudó que hiciéramos la tarea.
4. Ella dudó de que hiciéramos la tarea.

Estos son unos ejemplos que utilizan el verbo «dudar». ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de este verbo cuando es acompañado con «que»?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No hay diferencia y ambas formas (con y sin *de*) son perfectamente válidas.

La diferencia radica en si lo que se tiene en duda es un sustantivo y no una oración subordinada.  En el último caso, hay que emplear la forma con *de*:

- Dudo que sea una persona antipática. <sub>(*válido*, subordinada sin *de*)</sub>
- Dudo de que sea una persona antipática. <sub>(*válido*, subordinada con *de*)</sub>
- Dudo su antipatía. <sub>(***inválido***, sustantivo sin *de*)</sub>
- Dudo de su antipatía. <sub>(*válido*, sustantivo con *de*)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

```
Dudar [algo]
```

significa "cuestionar algo". Significa que no te lo crees.

- Dudo [que estemos en las nubes] = No creo que estemos en las nubes (difícil de creer).
- Ella dudó [que hiciéramos la tarea] = Ella no creyó que hiciéramos la tarea.

  Dudar de

significa tener dudas, creer **parcialmente**. Surgen preguntas en torno al tema.

- Ella dudó de que hiciéramos la tarea = Ella no terminó de creer que la hiciéramos.

Por tanto,

> Dudar algo = no creerlo (tajante).
>
> Dudar de algo = no creerlo del todo (parcialmente).

No obstante, "dudar [algo]" se puede usar con pronombres o con subordinadas sustantivas (Dudo eso, lo dudo, dudo que...), pero no con sustantivos (*  *Dudo el relato*)